# Permissão em diretórios para todo o domínio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando criar uma pasta e atribuir a ela permissões de leitura:

```
public static void createFolder(string path) {
    DirectorySecurity securityRules = new DirectorySecurity();
    securityRules.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"EMPRESA\account1", FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Allow));
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path, securityRules);
}
```

Gostaria de permitir o acesso a essa pasta para qualquer login do domínio. Como devo deixar o `@Dominio\usuarios` para fazer isso?

Grato!

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398398/7762411 (em inglês)

Comment: Eu havia tentado a dica desse tópico, mas aparentemente todos os usuários teriam acesso, e eu gostaria de restringir a um domínio só :/

Comment: Passa o usuário everyone do dominio